# Documentation of "%! TeX" codes

Tags: editors, texworks, magic-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When and why should I use %!TEX TS-program and %!TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/when-and-why-should-i-use-tex-ts-program-and-tex-encoding)

I want to create a list of "%! TeX" codes to a documentation file for my template and want it to be as complete, relevant and correct as possible and need a list of good on-line references that I can use as a basis and references.

I only found a few samples at

- [texworks TipsAndTricks](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/TipsAndTricks)
- [teworks manual.pdf](http://ftp.ctex.org/pub/tex/tools/editors/TeXworks/manual.pdf)

Comment: You're not asking for exactly the same thing, but all answers to your question would also be an answer to my question. I think it's good to keep the information in one place (and it'd actually be great if you could add any further insights you have to the other question!).