# How can I figure out which parameters are passed to xelatex by Rstudio?

Tags: xetex, r, sweave

I'm using Rstudio to create a nice pdf report using sweave and xelatex. I can process the sweave file in Rstudio, but I'm trying to wrap this into a script, so I need to figure out what parameters are being passed to xelatex - any ideas how to figure that out?

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the small question-mark icon next to the pulldown menu specifying the TeX engine in RStudio Sweave preferences, it will take you to the following web page, which outlines the options that RStudio passes automatically:

- [Customizing LaTeX options](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/latex_program?version=0.97.449&mode=desktop)

By default, RStudio passes `-file-line-error` and `synctex=-1` (there appears to be a typo in the page; the option is `synctex` not `synctec`).

Additionally, it will pass the `-shell-escape` option if the "Enable shell escape commands" box is clicked.

RStudio also understands the [per-file engine directives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693).