# Compile master file in pdflatex

Tags: miktex, texworks, multiple-files

I am using miktex, texworks and pdflatex to compile my document, which is in multiple parts.  When compiling the main file (which includes all of the other parts using \include{}) it works fine, however when compiling the child parts I hit the problem of them not being complete documents (they only have a section command and the contents of that section).  This means I have to have the main file open in the background and keep alt-tabbing when I want to recompile the document.  Is there a way to tell it that when I compile one of the child parts it should actually compile the main file?

Comment: Texworks support socalled magic comments where you can specify what the master file is. Just Google "Texworks magic comments"

Comment: http://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/

Comment: Thanks @daleif, easy to find when you know what to google for ;)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/73

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @daleif's comment above I found the answer to be adding

```
% !Tex root = main.tex
```

to the top of the child files.