# My document won't typeset, i did something wrong

Tags: errors

I accidentally tried to typeset my document by pressing shift+alt+t (mac), and i know it's only supposed to be just cmd+t, but a lot of my other key bindings are done through shift+alt+(something). Now the problem is, that my document won't typeset at all, it just gives me this:
[image]

What do i do?

Comment: Use `pdflatex` instead of `pdftex`.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is TeXshop and you accidentally hit command-shift-T instead of just command-T. If so, either use the Typeset menu to switch from TeX to LaTeX, or else change the dropdown box adjacent to the Typeset button from TeX to LaTeX.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/when-and-why-should-i-use-tex-ts-program-and-tex-encoding)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at last it is solved in the comments ...