# When and why should I use % !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8" directive?

Tags: compiling, editors, input-encodings, magic-comment

I often see the following lines are included at the beginning of the tex files:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
```

Directives started with **`% !TEX`** are explained thoroughly in this [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78103/36534), but I didn't find useful explanation about `% !Mode::`.

So I hope someone can explain:

1. How the `!Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"` directive works?
2. What else we could fill in the double quotation marks besides `TeX:UTF-8`?
3. When and why we should use (or not to use) `% !Mode`?
4. What is the differences between `% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"` and `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode`

Comment: The first two are directives understood by TeXShop and TeXworks, the last one is for some other editor/front-end, I guess Kile (which doesn't understand directives starting with `!TEX`, as far as I know).

Comment: @egreg: The last one is (also? only?) winedt.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just made a fast google lookup, it's indeed possible that it is WinEdt and not Kile. You surely know that I'm not a user of the former and I tell you I'm not of the latter either.

Comment: @egreg: It is certainly winedt (I'm using it) but I don't know if other editors use this syntax too.