# Unrecognized Command in pst-asr?

Tags: trees, linguistics, pst-asr

I'm trying to do autosegmental representation using pst-asr, but I am getting an unrecognized command error on `\asr`.  All I've done is use the sample code from the documentation, but it still won't compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{pst-asr.tex}{true}{false}
\IfFileExists{pstricks.tex}{true}{false}

\asr ki:p\endasr
\end{document}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling with latex+dvips? You can't compile this as shown with pdflatex.

Comment: I think I've figured it out.  I changed the compiling settings through the Build and View, and now I'm getting output. Thanks, @AlanMunn

Comment: I've voted to close this since the general problem is the same even if you are not using a Mac. For a list of editors that support the `% !TEX TS-program = ` syntax see [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693).