# How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography

Tags: natbib, urls, apa-style, bibdesk, apacite

I am really new to LaTeX and I need a comprehensive solution for my Thesis

I have this problem since two days and I couldn't find any solution in any other post.

I work with BibDesk on Mac 
And I used Packages `apacite` and `natbib`

```
@article{Ha89,
Author = {Peter M. Haas},
Date-Added = {2017-02-06 21:15:57 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-02-06 21:45:06 +0000},
Journal = {International Organization},
Lastchecked = {03/02/2010 12:54},
Number = {3},
Pages = {377-403},
Publisher = {Peter Haas},
Read = {0},
Title = {Do regimes matter? Epistemic communities and Mediterranean pollution control},
Urldate = { http://www.jstor.org/stable/2706652},
Volume = {43},
Year = {1989}}
```

this is a stripped version of my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.5in, includefoot]{geometry}  
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% REFERENCE PREAMBLE
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{biblatex-apa}                                                  
% Bullet preamble
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\diamond$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
% graphics preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}   %Allows you to import images
\usepackage{float}      %Allows for control of float positions
%HEADER AND FOOTER STUFF
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{amssymb}
%Zeilenabstand 1,5 wenn aktiviert 
\usepackage{setspace}\makeatletter\newcommand{\MSonehalfspacing}{\setstretch{1.44}\ifcase \@ptsize \relax\setstretch {1.448}\or\setstretch {1.399}\or\setstretch {1.433}\fi}\newcommand{\MSdoublespacing}{\setstretch {1.92}\ifcase \@ptsize \relax\setstretch {1.936}\or\setstretch {1.866}\or\setstretch{1.902}\fi}\makeatother\MSonehalfspacing %Zeilenabstand Code fertig
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}   %allows for clickable reference
%                       BEGIN OF DOCUMENT
\citeA{source}
%                       REFERENCES 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{Identifying the Regime}}
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{List of References}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}} 
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.9\itemsep}
\bibliography{/User/Desktop/Thesis/references/mybib.bib}                  
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section {\numberline{}References}                                                       \end{document}
```

I would like to have the bibliography entry include a retrieved from

[image]

I tried to deactivate `hyperref` – as suggested in another post – but it didn't work.
I also tried to activate and deactivate `natbib` and `apacite` as well.

I would really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 7):

Three suggestions:

- Don't load both the `apacite` and the `natbib` packages; instead, run either

  ```
  \usepackage{apacite}
  ```

  or

  ```
  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
  ```

  (Use the latter if you wish to use the natbib-like citation commands, e.g., `\citet` and `\citep`).
- Do familiarize yourself with the [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf) of the `apacite` package. In particular, the user guide provides lots more information about all options (including `natbibapa`) that the package recognizes.
- Don't use the bibliography style named `apa` -- it dates back to 1992.  Really! Instead, run

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  ```

  for a bibliography style that implements version 6.03 of the APA guide.

Incidentally, your sample bib entry -- which I assume you downloaded from some Internet repository -- contains two serious errors: The field named `Urldate` should be named `Url` (after all, the contents of field are a URL string, not a date...), and the field currently named `Lastchecked` should be named `Urldate`. Moral of the story: Don't place unfounded trust and confidence in material obtained "from the Internet". By all means, *verify*. I've made two further adjustments in the bib entry: In the `title` field, I've placed curly braces around the words "Epistemic" and "Mediterranean, so that they won't be typeset as "epistemic" and "mediterranean", and I've changed `-` to `--` in the `pages` field, to instruct LaTeX to create a proper en-dash.

---

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Ha89,
Author     = {Peter M. Haas},
Date-Added = {2017-02-06 21:15:57 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-02-06 21:45:06 +0000},
Journal    = {International Organization},
Urldate    = {03/02/2010 12:54},
Number     = {3},
Pages      = {377--403},
Publisher  = {Peter Haas},
Read       = {0},
Title      = {Do regimes matter? {Epistemic} communities and {Mediterranean} pollution control},
Url        = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2706652},
Volume     = {43},
Year       = {1989}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Ha89}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best current implementation of a true APA style is the `biblatex-apa` style. Here's a sample document using it.  If you want to use the 'Retrieved from' field, you need to name it correctly, the `biblatex` field name is `urldate` and the formatting of the date has to be correct too:  YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (if you need exact times, although they won't be printed in the output) or YYYY-MM-DD if you just need the day. (I also added some braces in your title so that the capitalization is correct.)

This needs to be compiled using `biber` (not `bibtex`). This should be configurable in your editor.  See the following question for ways to do this automatically:

- [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693)

```
\documentclass{article}
% this is a way of including a bib entry into a document for testing
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@article{Ha89,
Author = {Peter M. Haas},
Date-Added = {2017-02-06 21:15:57 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-02-06 21:45:06 +0000},
Journal = {International Organization},
urldate = {2010-02-03T12:54:00},
Number = {3},
Pages = {377-403},
Publisher = {Peter Haas},
Read = {0},
Title = {Do regimes matter? {Epistemic} communities and {Mediterranean} pollution control},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2706652},
Volume = {43},
Year = {1989}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\section{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % replace this with your actual bibfile name
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{hyperref} load this (last) if you want live links
\begin{document}
This is an in text citation: \textcite{Ha89}.  This is a parenthetical one: \parencite{Ha89}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wow Thank you very much Alan.

So I have to change the editor configuration from biblatex to biber? How do I do that?

I downloaded Biber and I tried your coding but it didn't work and I got an error "Option clash for package biblatex"

I'm sorry, I really am a raw recruit.

Comment: You're using a Mac. What editor are you using?  You shouldn't have had to download anything if you have a current MacTeX installed.  And you should remove all other bibliography related code from your preamble and document. (I'm assuming the error you get isn't from this document.)

Comment: Do you have a reference for, or some other means to support, the view that "The best current implementation of a true APA style is the biblatex-apa style"? I suspect it might be news to Erik Meijer, the maintainer of the `apacite` package, that his package doesn't do a good job of implementing the 6th edition of the APA's bibliography formatting guidelines.

Comment: @Mico Maybe that's a bit strong, but `biblatex-apa` "typesets just about every useful example from (APA 6.11)–(APA 6.21) and (APA 7.01)–(APA 7.11)." so  it conforms with APA 7.  I don't know if this is a substantive change from APA 6 or not, and I'm not trying to impugn the `apacite` package.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. (I must confess to not knowing if there are any meaningful differences, at least as bibliography formatting goes, between versions 6 and 7 of "The Manual".)

Comment: Thank you very much, Alan. I found the bug. Everything works properly now. Turns out I used some contradicting commands in addition. I think I'll go with the apacite-option.

Comment: @AlanMunn Hey Alan, this post is the closest one I need but when I try what you say above, my first page becomes something like `=0pt [],n;`. I am trying to write my manuscript with elsevier's cas-dc.cls format and I need to use APA6 style. I have tried a lot last 2 days but nothing worked for me. Can you please help me, I am about the gone crazy.