# IPA Symbols in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, tipa, zotero

Does anybody know how to get bibtex to output ʔ (and other IPA symbols)? I need to cite the following article:

Blevins, Juliette. 2001. Klamath /sʔ/ Clusters. International Journal of American Linguistics 67 (4): 467–474.

I can't figure out how to get (PDF)Latex to print the glottal stop in the title when generating references using bibtex. (This problem can be generalized to any IPA symbol.) Normally that character can be printed using \textipa{P} (with the package tipa).

Here's the bibtex entry for the article. If anyone has an answer that can be implemented in Zotero, that would be especially nice.

```
@article{blevins2001,
  title = {Klamath /sʔ/ {{Clusters}}},
  volume = {67},
  number = {4},
  journal = {International Journal of American Linguistics},
  author = {Blevins, Juliette},
  year = {2001},
  pages = {467--474},
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `biblatex +  biber`?  Biber natively understands   `utf8`.

Comment: I did not. Can you elaborate?

Comment: See [biblatex for beginners](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/2693). Also [bibtex vs biber and biblatex vs natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693). Since you're a linguist, APA style is quite useable, so [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812/2693) will be helpful. And *Semantics and Pragmatics* has a `biblatex` version of the LSA Unified bibliography style: https://github.com/semprag/biblatex-sp-unified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is to put the `\textipa{P}` into the `.bib` file, so the `ipa.bib` looks like the following:

```
@article{blevins2001,
  title = {Klamath {/s\textipa{P}/} {{Clusters}}},
  volume = {67},
  number = {4},
  journal = {International Journal of American Linguistics},
  author = {Blevins, Juliette},
  year = {2001},
  pages = {467--474},
}
```

Note the curly braces around `/s\textipa{P}/`, they quote the string preventing it from being lowercased by `bibtex`.
Also, the document doesn't have to use `inputenc` just for the sake of using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` anymore.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
See~\cite{blevins2001} for details.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ipa}
\end{document}
```

The result looks the same as for the previous answer [image: IPA char in references]

Comment: This works too. (I thought I had tried this, but I think I forgot the braces.) Also, I can get Zotero to output this to bibtex if its surrounded by <pre>...</pre> in Zotero, i.e. <pre>{/s\textipa{P}/}</pre> .

Comment: Good to hear that. I never used Zotero, so I can only guess which way would work in it.

Answer (score 1):

For pdfLaTeX you could define this character in the document preamble, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{294}{\textipa{P}}
\begin{document}
See~\cite{blevins2001} for details.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ipa}
\end{document}
```

where `ipa.bib` contains your bibtex entry as is in UTF-8 encoding. The result is [image: IPA char in references]

Comment: I don't recommend this approach: `bibtex` is NOT able to deal with UTF-8 encoded `.bib` files. This is independent of how you set the encoding of your document. So this really only works by accident.

Comment: For what it's worth, this worked (accidentally or not) when I input ʔ directly into the bib file, but it did not work when I put it in Zotero and tried to get it to generate it automatically.