# default bibliography style in memoir class

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, apa-style

I am writing my thesis on the memoir class. I dont seem to figure out how to make `natbib` or else `biblatex` to work in this environment and so am having problems using the `citet` or `shortcite` commands to either have `Author(Year)` in the intext citations and `AuthorA et. al (Year)` in cases with more than two authors.The memoir manual doesn't seem to explicitly show how to formally use citations (or I am expecting too much from the manual). My institution uses the APA style and so am caged to make this work. Relating to the bibliography, this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\file.bib}
\end{document}
```

and from the `file.bib` I got;

```
@article{andreoni2011avoiding,
    Author = {Andreoni, J and Rao, Justin M and Trachtman, Hannah},
    Journal = {Empathy, and Charitable Giving, memo},
    Title = {Avoiding The Ask: A Field Experiment on Altruism},
    Year = {2011}
}
```

Any suggestions please?

**Hyperref:**

Here is what I do to have my citations `url` and the `ToC` to hyperlink and in blue coulor. I intend to change the color before submitting my thesis as this is not acceptable in my University. Either way, I need to be able to quickly find an intext citation entry in my document as I develop it. I am thinking coloring will help me.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, 
    urlcolor     = blue, 
    linkcolor    = blue, 
    citecolor   = blue 
}
```

The error message is that I am using a `caption` command with memoir class.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is exactly. `memoir` allows you to use any bibliography system you like; there is no "default" for it. But in your example code you should write `\bibliography{file}` not `\file.bib` if your bibliography file is called `file.bib`.  You also shouldn't have the second `\bibliographystyle` command.

Comment: See the examples in the answers here for two ways to do APA bibliographies: [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812/2693). Both are compatible with `memoir`.

Comment: check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex

Comment: Thanking you gladly. I agree I needed to indicate `\bibliography{file}`. The links too have exposed more options. Do you have an idea why I get error warnings when I use the `usepackage{hyperref}` to customize my citation and `url` to have appear clickable and in blue color? see edited MWE above.

Comment: Having fixed my citation problems and reloaded the `hyperref` command, all seems OK now. I have my colored highlighting. I also did a thorough background check with the `memoir` manual and that has been helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- The `memoir` document class neither provides nor expects any particular bibliography style.
- If you want to use natbib-like commands such as `\citet` and `\citep` while using the [apacite](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite) citation management package, you should load `apacite` with the option `natbibapa`:

  ```
  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
  ```

  Do *not* load `natbib` separately.
- Don't issue two `\bibliographystyle` instructions.
- The argument of `\bibliography` should be `file`, not `\file.bib`, right?
- Whatever else you decide to do, you really, really need to update the *contents* of the bibliographic entry. After all, the piece [was published](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/691703) in the June 2017 issue of the Journal of Political Economy.

  ```
  @article{andreoni-rao-trachtman:2017,
    author  = {James Andreoni and Justin M. Rao and Hannah Trachtman},
    title   = {Avoiding the Ask: A Field Experiment on 
               Altruism, Empathy, and Charitable Giving},
    journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
    volume  = {125},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {625--653},
    year    = {2017},
    doi     = {10.1086/691703},
    eprint  = {https://doi.org/10.1086/691703},
  }
  ```

And the revised MWE might look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{andreoni-rao-trachtman:2017}
\bibliography{file}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is now helpful on my end. The only thing I am left grappling with is to make the first author surname appear with _et. al_ for cases with more than two authors. I am currently reading the `apacite` **manual** to see how I can make this work.

Comment: thank you for the heads up on the bibliographic content. I think I compiled my `dotbibfile` at a time when this work was not published at the **Journal of Political Economy**. My bad.

Comment: @GeorgeKariuki - For bibliographic entries with 3 to 5 authors, I believe that APA style is to list all authors the first time a piece is cited and to use the "firstautor et al" truncation convention for subsequent citation call-outs. Special rules apply for pieces with 6 or more authors. Do consult the APA guidelines for all the (painful!) details...

Comment: A good (painful) thing to read the **APA manual guidelines**. I literally need to do nothing if **APA style** is what I have to comply with so yes, all authors get cited in the first instance but in subsequent times, I get what I needed. Thank you.