# \bibliographystyle{apalike} invalid

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, errors, apa-style

I am trying to do APA citation (Name, Year).

However, when I try to compile:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

I get this error:

! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \bibliographystyle{apalike}

Anyone know why?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tgschola}% or any other font package you like
\usepackage{setspace}
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\restoreparindent
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{pictures/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\rhead{Team Frank}
\lhead{MINE 404}
\chead{Project Report}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Spend a whole night trying to figure this out with no success.

Comment: You can't use a `\bibliographystyle` command with `biblatex`. If you want to use an APA style with `biblatex`, use `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` and compile using `biber` not `bibtex`.  See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701) and [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793).

Comment: `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa` should only be necessary if you must really follow the APA manual. If you just want a style that is like APA ("`apalike`") or a general author-year style, then `style=authoryear` might be the better choice.

Comment: @moewe I agree, although the default `author-year` has some idiosyncrasies that will unfortunately always require some tweaking I think (e.g. the use of "In" with journals.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes that is true. Fortunately many tweaks are quite easy. Often the default styles are easier to modify than contributed styles that are heavily customised to satisfy a particular style guide. Even supposedly trivial changes can be quite complicated with `biblatex-apa` or `biblatex-chicago`, so I would only use those styles if I have follow the respective style guide or if I can guarantee that the changes I have to apply are indeed minimal. In my experience many people that use `apalike` are not actually after full APA compliance, but rather generic author-year citations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing commands from two different bibliography methods.  The `\bibliographystyle` command cannot be used with `biblatex`, and is used with a different bibliography package such as `natbib` or `apacite`, or with no package at all.

`biblatex` uses a different method of styling the bibliography, and the style is specified in the options to the `\usepackage{biblatex}` command.

There are various ways to get an APA conforming bibliography style, both with `biblatex` and without it.  The following question shows you two ways:

- [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812/2693)

Summarizing, you can either:

1. Remove the `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` from your document and instead use:

   ```
   \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
   ```

If you use this method, you should use `biber` to process the bibliography.

or

2. Remove the `\usepackage{biblatex}` from your document, and instead use:

   ```
       \usepackage{apacite}
       \bibliographystyle{apacite}
   ```

or

```
        \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

If you use this method, you should use `bibtex` to process the bibliography.

For more general information see also:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
- [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793)