# What is the "!TEX option"?

Tags: latexmk, shell-escape, ide, latextools

I am using the Atom editor with the [latextools](https://atom.io/packages/latextools) package (a port of the similar one for Sublime) and I can write for example

```
% !TEX option = -shell-escape
```

in the begining of my document to make it escape the shell (and use the Minted package).

My question is, where does this command come from? Is it from the latextools package or is it some standard syntax? Is it portable to other IDE?

When building I see this:

```
latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -latexoption="-shell-escape" "main.tex"
```

Comment: Which part are you asking about? The `!TEX ...` syntax is quite common to lots of editors: see [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693).  The `-shell-escape` is typical shell syntax.

Comment: Just to point out: the `!TEX` syntax is pretty broadly useable. The `option` part is unique to LaTeXTools AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the duplicate. This pattern was a bit tricky for me to search for, mainly because of the leading "!".