# How change TeXShop default engine depending on file type

Tags: editors, texshop, scripts, markdown

How do I get TeXShop to open with a certain engine already selected when it opens a certain file type? Right now the default engine is always `LaTeX`, which is fine when I am opening `.tex` files. However when I open `.md` files in TeXShop I want the default engine to be something called `pandoc-pdf`. Is there something I can change so that I don't have to select this from the drop-down menu, and it is automatically selected?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can combine a Markdown comment (as described here: [Comments in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4823468/958220)) with a TeXShop directive  (as described here: [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693)) and have the best of both worlds. Without the markdown comment, `pandoc` will output the TeXShop directive line.

```
[//]: % !TEX TS-program = pandoc-pdf
```

TeXShop correctly sees this directive line, and `pandoc` correctly ignores it.

Comment: This works, but it requires me to add that line at the beginning of every `.md` file that I open in TeXShop in order to typeset correctly. Is there a way to simply get TeXShop to set its default engine based on the type of file it is opening?

Comment: No that's not possible I'm afraid.

Comment: One possibility would be to use the Stationery function of TeXShop to create a `.md` template with that line included.  Then you choose New from Stationery to start new files.  Alternatively, just create a macro in TeXShop to add that line quickly.