# Can I configure latexmk to respect the TS-program directive?

Tags: latexmk

I like latexmk but I use a variety of engines on files in the same folder.  I'm trying to write a `latexmkrc` file that will look in the first few lines of the tex file for something like

```
% !TEX TS-program=xelatex
```

and then decide which tex engine to run for that file.

I know that the configuration variable `$pdf_mode` can determine which engine to use, but I'd like to do it dynamically for each target tex file.  It seems like overriding the right subroutine could work.  I tried reading the `latexmk.pl` source code, but it is several thousand lines long and I'm having trouble finding the right place.

Comment: You can probably ask the maintainer for this as a feature request. My worry is probably that there might not be any common syntax for this. Should latexmk then also know arara syntax?

Comment: You could try [DiCy](https://yitzchak.github.io/dicy/comparison-of-builders.html) instead of latexmk

Comment: From what I could understand of the source (disclaimer: I don't know Perl), this would only be possible Latexmk: 1) executes whatever is in `.latexmkrc`; 2) processes the command line arguments; 3) parses input files given in the command line. To have `.latexmkrc` parse the input file I think you would need it to do 2, 3, and then 1, otherwise `.latexmkrc` doesn't yet know about input files...

Comment: Latexmk maintainer here: This feature is on my list of things that I would like to implement in latexmk.  But when that will happen I don't know

Comment: Assuming you’re using TeXShop why not just use the xelatexmk engine? You’ll have to enable it if you haven’t done so already. Read the documentation in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/inactive/Latexmk`. You can open `~/Library/TeXShop` with the menu item in the TeXShop menu.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for responding, and I'm glad this is on the list.  I have some experience with perl so I may be able to contribute, if you'd be willing to point me in the right direction.  Feel free to email me if you want.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I am a long time TeXShop user, but I'm thinking of migrating to VS Code, since I use it for all my other projects.  Plus I am working on something that would support non-Mac users I work with.

Comment: @daleif latexmk's documentation says to go here first, then contact the maintainer directly.  And we did get the maintainer. `:-)` I *think* that `TS-program` is somewhat of a standard syntax, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84687/1402).  It lists several IDEs that respect the directive, despite the "namespacing" prefix.

Comment: @DG' thanks for letting me know about DiCy.  I will check it out.  I like latexmk because its config files are perl programs so there's a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I, too, use latexmk and would love to see your feature request implemented