# Compiling the main document from a chapter file

Tags: chapters, compiling, input

I have a main document calling on several different chapter files. What I would like to do is have split-screen open with one chapter tex file on one side and a compiled pdf on the other side that I can update as I go using the keyboard shortcuts ***from my chapter tex file*** instead of having to exit, go find my main file and compile it from there, and *then* come back to my chapter file.

I've seen plenty of answers instructing how to compile the main document to show only a single chapter by using *include* instead of *input*. But that doesn't solve the issue of compiling the chapter file while working on it. Those answers still require going back to the main document to compile.

As a bad hack right now, I've input my preamble file into my chapter file and written begin{document} stuff etc while I'm working on it so that I can just get it to compile temporarily. The issue is that I have to % out the begin{document} and preamble stuff if I ever want to compile my main document and I'm certain there has to be a better way to do it.

Please help!

Comment: It is not what you ask, but you should take a look to the `docmute` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a separate `onechapter.tex` that has the same preamble and then includes whatever chapter I'm currently working on.  That solves the problem with your bad hack that you have a file that doesn't compile.

To avoid switching from the chapter's source to `onechapter.tex`, you could begin the chapter with
`% !TEX root = onechapter.tex`
See [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/107497)