# Get Overleaf to compile main document instead of \input chapter?

Tags: overleaf

I am writing a document with multiple chapters on Overleaf. When I try to compile a chapter, it does not compile the main document but the included file, which results in errors. Is there a way to have Overleaf compile the main document when I compile a chapter? I have seen similar questions, but usually they involve answers that might not apply to Overleaf.

Comment: Isnt't there a "main document" setting in Overleafs project settings?

Comment: You could also try `% !TEX root = ...` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/107497 (and let us know if Overleaf understands it).

Comment: @Teepeemm The `%!` directives don't work in Overleaf (I _know_ it, I work there :-) ) We do however try to detect for the presence of `\documentclass` so if the chapter file is open in the editor and it contains `\documentclass` (which doesn't really make sense), the Overleaf compiler will treat it as a main file (as long as it's open in the editor).

Comment: Is your chapter contain `\documentclass{}` command?

Comment: No no `\documentclass` in the chapter file

Comment: @user0 can you confirm that the main document is identified as the main document in Overleaf's settings?...sorry to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this command:

```
\include{xyz}
%\include{chapters/xyz} %using path, chapters folder
```

This command allows you to include a particular `xyz.tex` file into another file. From the main document you can include a/more chapter(s) to it and compile. On the other hand, you can include the `main.tex` into a particular chaper `xyz.tex` file and compile it.

**Teepeemm** added:

> they're using \include (or \input) already, but that they click
> "compile" while they're editing the included file. Overleaf tries to
> compile the included file instead of the including file, and this
> results in numerous errors because everything up to and including
> \begin{document} is missing.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think OP's problem is that they're using `\include` (or `\input`) already, but that they click "compile" while they're editing the included file.  Overleaf tries to compile the included file instead of the including file, and this results in numerous errors because everything up to and including `\begin{document}` is missing.

Comment: yes @Teepeemm that is correct thank you