# Is there a way to always compile the main document?

Tags: compiling, overleaf, subfiles

I am using overleaf and I have a main document and several subfiles. Is there a way of always having the main file compile even if I have selected and I am editing subfiles?
Cheers in advance,
Blake

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_choose_which_file_is_the_main_tex_file_in_a_project_on_Overleaf%3F

Comment: Yes, I had already found that and looked into it, however, that doesn't solve the problem. If I press compile when on a subfile only compiles that subfile. I just wondered if there was a way always to force it to compile the main text irrespective of what subfile is open.

Comment: ask the overleaf support. They can check your project setup.

Comment: Alternatively just use `\input` and `\include` instead of using `subfiles`, that way there would be no `\documentclass` in your sub-files.

Comment: Actually some old question I can find claims it happens even without documentclass [Get Overleaf to compile main document instead of \input chapter? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621316/get-overleaf-to-compile-main-document-instead-of-input-chapter?rq=1). Maybe it's fixed now.

Comment: @user202729 Overleaf literally searches for a line that starts with `\documentclass` (whitespace ignored) within the first 30kB of the file contents, so something else must have been happening for that user. See https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/blob/4688cb7b5485cdb58e4fa0da23d671a1828bdc69/services/web/app/src/Features/Documents/DocumentHelper.js#L38 and https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/blob/dc2097e6845e5d86050498f6be1153140a731608/services/web/app/src/Features/Project/ProjectRootDocManager.js#L29

Answer (score 5):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

To me it seems that always wanting to compile the main file quite defies the purpose of using `subfiles`, but if you wish, you can do that by replacing

```
\documentclass[...]{subfiles}
```

with

```
\csname documentclass\endcsname[...]{subfiles}
```

in the sub-file.
This dirty hack will trick our compiler into not seeing the `\documentclass` command and thus compiling the main file instead.

Comment: That works wonders cheers. I was just using subfiles to split the document up. Cheers for the help.

Comment: @BlakeRowan Cool -- great to hear it works. Note that then a simple `\input` would do the trick just the same, without the overhead of the non-trivialities `subfiles` is doing.