# is there a reference of %!TeX directives?

Tags: magic-comment

Well, can't find if this has been asked here before, and failing to found good answer with search engines (I tried only with Qwant and DuckDuckGo.) Is there somewhere a good and complete reference somewhere on these

```tex
% !TeX directives
```

put at the top of files by some editors (or IDE like editing environments)?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/when-and-why-should-i-use-tex-ts-program-and-tex-encoding/84687#84687

Comment: (some editors also have their own magic comments, you should consult the documentation of whichever editor you use)

Comment: Thanks Sam. Seeing that support list let me think there's a kind of (de facto?) standard, isn't it? Or you mean it's some hazard if things are so? (in that later case, question can be closed.)

Comment: Not really a coincidence, I think one editor started and others adopted the magic comments and sometimes added custom one.

Comment: They come from TeXshop originally

Comment: Many thanks Sam and Joseph

Comment: The question is not about when or why, but: a full list of allowed directives and established rules (for example absence or more space between percent sign and exclamation mark, etc.) And the answer appears to be: there's no kind of standardisation and it's the jungle (answer not found in page pointed as duplication.)