# TeXShop compiles only once when using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, texshop

If I use TeXShop with pdfLaTeX then the document is automatically compiled as often as necessary to get the TOC and bibliography and all else done.

However, if I use TeXShop with XeLaTeX (I need to use Arial) then the process is run only once.

Is there a setting somewhere to activate automatic multiple passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic compilation that you are seeing with `pdflatex` is likely because you have set your default compilation engine to be `pdflatemk`.  The regular `pdflatex` engine doesn't do multiple combinations automatically. But there are `mk` versions for all three engines, and you can select them by using a "magic comment" in the first line of your document. You can type these lines yourself, or you can use the Macros->Program menu item to select from the list which will insert the relevant magic comment for you.

For automatic `pdflatex` compilation:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdfLaTeXmk
```

For automatic `xelatex` compilation:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTexmk
```

For automatic `lualatex` compilation:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeXmk
```

If these don't work for you, you may need to move the relevant Engines from the `Inactive/Latexmk` folder to the main `Engines` folder inside your `~/Library/TeXShop` folder, which you can navigate to from within TeXShop from the TeXShop menu item.

For more information on magic comments, see:

- [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693)

Comment: Thank you! I had just figured it out myself a few minutes ago. Seeing that pdfLaTeX is actually called through pdflatexmk I just tried xelatexmk and it worked!