Error while compiling multiple tex files on TeXworks
I am writing my thesis using a multiple.tex file. I have a main file that calls different subtex files. The main file works properly while compiling. However, when I am trying to compile the subfile, it shows the following error :
(chapter1.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \chapter
{Introduction}
?
My subfile starts with the following code:
\chapter{Introduction} 
\label{Chapter1}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/Chapter1/} }

Can I directly compile my subfile to open the main PDF? Right now, I have to again revert to the main file to compile the full PDF.
I am using TeXworks with the MiKTeX console on macOS.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

What document class are you using? Are you perhaps trying to compile the chapter files directly without a top-level file containing the class?

@JosephWright I am using the document class "report." I am using the 'include" command in the main file. I am starting my subfile with the command \chapter{} . I have edited my question a bit with the correct code for the subfile

Your subfile is a chunk of a document, you cannot compile it "as is". If you want to see previews of the child files, see here.

@Fran, I borrowed the entire Tex file from a friend who wrote his thesis using the same subfile. The only difference is that he is running the tex file on Tex Studio on macOS. The same code works perfectly fine on his computer with Tex Studio. And one can compile the subfiles also. I am using the same Tex file just on TeXworks. I think the problem is associated with the different Tex software. I think the code is correct.

ah it does support that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/when-and-why-should-i-use-tex-ts-program-and-tex-encoding/78352#78352

@SaurabhPant it is unrelated to the tex system, it is purely a feature of the editor you are using. You need to tell the editor which file to process if you do not want to process the current file. according to the linked answer texworks supports the ts-root comment to specify that.

typo in the previous comment: !TeX root =   not !TeX ts-root

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your answer. I can compile the subfiles now. I just had a last question. I am using \input and \include as commands to use the subfiles. I can compile the subfiles; however, they open just the main PDF file. It doesn't take me to the place where the edit is made. I have to scroll through the compiled PDF. Can you suggest what I should add to the subfile so that it takes me directly to the place where the text is edited?

sorry I don't use texworks at all

@SaurabhPant No, you never can compile a subfile.tex  that start with \chapter because is not in a document environment, and moreover that command does not exist except when defined  by the document class or elsewhere before, that explain your error in line 2. The % !TeX root    = main.tex code is just a trick of some editors to change the target of the compilation from the open file to the  main.tex, that should be a true document.The subfile with a \chapter{} is not a true  (complete) LaTeX document, just a a chunk of text with a  misplaced command, as valid as \whatever{}.
